# indexpath.section .. how in tableview into sections?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a table view with sections and each section has its own array ... I have 13 sections,And each section has different topics.
How do I do in the method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How do I make the switch?

```
Switch(indexpath.section)
```

Comment: hi just check for condition  switch(indexpath.section) { case 0:// do the cell to be displayed break; same way for all other sections

Comment: You have the answer.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
`

`switch (indexPath.section)`
{

`case 0:
      cell.textLabel.text=@""; 
      break;`
.
.
.
 `case n:`

`//display whatever want 
break;`
`default:
break;`
`}
}`

Comment: I put what you told me ... but does not start the simulator

Comment: can u elaborate your issue @CristianRiccardi